# Pattern to safely establish a one to one bidirectional relationship

Tags: relationships

Let suppose we have 2 classes, `Pilot` and `Plane`, being in an optional one-to-one relationship. So a `Plane` might have a pilot when it's flying, but when it's standing in its hangar, it has none. Similar for the `Pilot`.

It would be just logical to hold a pointer to the `Plane` in the `Pilot` and a pointer to the `Pilot` in the `Plane`, accessible via getters and setters.

Constructing the setters so that a call on any of them establishes the bidirectional relationship is surprisingly hard. I was even more surprised that I couldn't find a suitable solution on the web as this construct seems to be common to me.

Does anyone know of concepts that would encapsulate such a relationship inside a class? Or an idiom to stick with normal getters/setters and still establish the relationship with one setPilot/setPlane call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that this will always be 1-1 (e.g., you wont get 2 pilots from a plane to represent pilot and co-pilot). Instead of trying to build this relationship into the Plane or Pilot classes, use a third class that provides the mapping. For lack of a better name, let's call it PilotPlaneMap here. This class could have the following public functions:

```
class PilotPlaneMap
{
public void RelatePilotAndPlane(Pilot pilot, Plane plane){..} //make the relationship here
public Pilot GetPilot(Plane plane){..} //retrieve the pilot related to given plane
public Plane GetPlane(Pilot pilot){..} //retrieve the plane related to given pilot

}
```

Not sure what language you are using, but internally you would make use of some hashmap to store the relationships. Two dictionaries could be used. One that maps Pilot->Plane, and the other maps Plane->Pilot. These are both set when calling RelatePilotAndPlane(). That's just one option.

Comment: I had hoped for a solution that keeps the getter/setter schema, without having the same pattern of code all over the project (there are of course many classes that are in a 1-to-1 relation). After all yours seems to be a reasonable solution, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the job for  a `FlightPlan`!

Answer (score 0):

I will preface this by saying I think that the mapping suggestion is better. However, I believe the code below will work:

```
public final class Pilot {
    private Plane plane;

    public Plane getPlane() {
        return plane;
    }

    public void setPlane(final Plane newPlane) {
        if (this.plane == newPlane)
            return;

        final Plane oldPlane = this.plane;
        this.plane = newPlane;

        if (oldPlane != null)
            oldPlane.setPilot(null);

        if (newPlane != null)
            newPlane.setPilot(this);

        this.plane = newPlane;
    }
}

public final class Plane {
    private Pilot pilot;

    public Pilot getPilot() {
        return pilot;
    }

    public void setPilot(final Pilot newPilot) {
        if (this.pilot == newPilot)
            return;

        final Pilot oldPilot = this.pilot;
        this.pilot = newPilot;

        if (oldPilot != null)
            oldPilot.setPlane(null);

        if (newPilot != null)
            newPilot.setPlane(this);

        this.pilot = newPilot;
    }
}
```

And some cursory testing:

```
    Plane plane1 = new Plane();
    Plane plane2 = new Plane();
    Pilot pilot1 = new Pilot();
    Pilot pilot2 = new Pilot();

    pilot1.setPlane(plane1);
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertNull(pilot2.getPlane());

    pilot2.setPlane(plane1);
    Assert.assertNull(pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot2.getPlane());

    pilot1.setPlane(null);
    pilot2.setPlane(null);
    Assert.assertNull(plane1.getPilot());
    Assert.assertNull(pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertNull(pilot2.getPlane());

    plane1.setPilot(pilot1);
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertNull(pilot2.getPlane());

    plane1.setPilot(pilot2);
    Assert.assertNull(pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot2.getPlane());

    plane1.setPilot(null);
    plane2.setPilot(null);

    plane1.setPilot(pilot1);
    plane2.setPilot(pilot2);
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertEquals(pilot1, plane1.getPilot());
    Assert.assertEquals(plane2, pilot2.getPlane());
    Assert.assertEquals(pilot2, plane2.getPilot());

    plane1.setPilot(pilot2);
    Assert.assertEquals(plane1, pilot2.getPlane());
    Assert.assertEquals(pilot2, plane1.getPilot());
    Assert.assertNull(pilot1.getPlane());
    Assert.assertNull(plane2.getPilot());
```

Answer (score 0):

> It would be just logical to hold a pointer to the Plane in the Pilot and a pointer to the Pilot in the Plane, accessible via getters and setters.

The pattern you are looking for is [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) (here e.g. in Ruby):

```
class Plane
    attr_accessor :pilot
end

class Pilot
  attr_accessor :plane
end

plane1=Plane.new
pilot1=Pilot.new
plane1.pilot=pilot1
pilot1.plane=plane1
```

Every time you want to know, who is pilot of *plane1*, you could ask the plane:

```
plane1.pilot
```

This solution is simple, intuitive - but has a small drawback:

*In order to cut the relation between both, you have to manipulate both instances.*

Another problem occurs if you at a later point decide, that you need a *JSON*-Representation of your Planes and their pilots. Then you have a circular dependency: *a plane has a pilot, which has a plane, which has a pilot* ... you get it?

Of course there are ways around this problem (e.g. in Java you have *@JsonManagedReferenc* and *@JsonBackReference* when using *JACKSON*).

In the context of [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) this is a common solution: building a *one-to-one*-Relation via *aggregation*. The framework takes care of the relational mapping.

On the other hand: like @user144552 said in his answer, a solution in form of a *Map* might be the way to go. If you are working *in-memory* building a *Map* is the fastest solution, since you have *O(1)* with a *Map*.

But if you were working wih a DB, you would have to query the *DB* and let the *DB* doing the *filtering*

It depends on the usecase, what kind of implementation seems useful.